# Php 8.0 won't execute phpmyadmin script, but runs simple phpinfo script perfectly

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

No matter which version of Ubuntu, I never have had a problem installing and running phpmyadmin.  Not so under 21.10.  I have purged and completely re-installed apache2, mysql, and php8.0, deleting the phpmyadmin database and all related account info.  Php executes a simple phpinfo script perfectly, but when I attempt to run phpmyadmin, its script displays but will not execute.  I must be missing something "obvious" but what?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution to my problem seems to reside in installing php.db, which provides a copy of the mysqli extension.  Now I'm trying to figure out php's path requirement for the extension.